# Python: break statement not working in for loop

Tags: python

Here's my code so far. I have a list initiated as below with a length of 3. The goal is to return the length of the longest list with the same same common prefix as `self.nums`.

```
self.nums = ['1', '2', '3']
ourPrefixLen = len(self.nums)   # outputs 3

dict_of_prefixes = {}    # to be populated

for url, list_blocks in chains.items():
    print("URL - ")
    print(url)
    print("list_blocks - ")
    print(list_blocks)

    for i in range(ourPrefixLen):
        print('i - ')
        print(i)
        print("self.nums[i] - ")
        print(self.nums[i])
        print("list_blocks[i] - ")
        print(list_blocks[i])
        if self.nums[i] != list_blocks[i]:
            print("BREAK")
            break
        print("NOOO")
        dict_of_prefixes[url] = list_blocks

print("HERE")

length = 0
longest = ""
for url, chain in dict_of_prefixes.items():
    if len(chain) > length:
        length = len(chain)
        longest = url
return longest
```

`chains` is a dictionary. Here's the test case I'm failing:

```
chains = {'a':['1', '2', '3'], 'b':['1','2','3'], 'c':['1','3','4','5']}
```

The result should be 3 (the length of the longest chain with the same common prefix as `self.nums`, but I'm getting 4 incorrectly (the length of `c`), so my code is still adding `c` to dict_of_prefixes even though it

Including all those print statements, this is the relevant output:

```
URL - 

c

list_blocks - 

['1', '3', '4', '5']

self.nums[i] - 

1

list_blocks[i] - 

1

self.nums[i] - 

2

list_blocks[i] - 

3

BREAK

HERE
```

So, this shows it is entering the Break statement case, and does NOT add `c` to `dict_of_prefixes`. So why is `c` still getting added to dict_of_prefixes?

Comment: "The goal is to return the length of the longest list with the same same common prefix as self.nums" ??

Comment: @jberrio yes- so in the example, when self.nums = [1,2,3], and given the dictionary with lists [1,2,3], [1,3,4,5], it should return 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of how you loop through and add all the `sublist` matches to `dict_of_prefixes`. What you're missing is the logic to when to actually add a list when it matches `self.num`.

Consider the snippet below, we only add something if the `is_match` remains `True` otherwise we break and don't even consider it (I've removed your `print`s for simplicity)

```
...

is_match = True # Assume that this sublist is a match
for i in range(ourPrefixLen):
  if self.nums[i] != list_blocks[i]:
      is_match = False
      break
if is_match:
  dict_of_prefixes[url] = list_blocks

...
```